# Replace a trac site with a basic redirect page

Tags: apache, trac

We have trac site set up to listen on /tracproj/, this swiftly passes control onto mod_python and does some python magic (I'm a php coder :-p);

anyway. I have a project at /tracproj/{projectname} and I'd like to replace all requests to that url with another page that redirects them elsewhere (We're migrating one trac to another bug tracking system)

The easiest method is to add a new entry in the httpd.conf to listen for that dir and redirect but it's a little messy :-D; I also don't seem to be able to get it to work :-p.

Is there any way - inside or as part of trac - to do what I'm after?

Comment: You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: I have no idea if this is a good solution, but there is a server-side redirect macro for Trac: http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/ServerSideRedirectPlugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up needing to keep the old site as an archive so we updated the templates to include a link to the new bug tracker in the header and changed the permissions of everyone to disable creating of new tickets.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried in Apache that hasn't worked? That seems like the simplest way to me.

I would suggest something along these lines:

```
Redirect /tracproj/whatever http://another.bug/tracking/system
```

To do it within Trac would, I believe, require adding (or writing) a Trac plugin.